# Passing a string that could hold several values(not an array)

Tags: java

```
public class ArithmeticTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        call(3, "+", 4, "7");
        call(3, "-", 4, "-1");
        call(3, "*", 4, "12");
        call(3, "@", 4, "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException");
        call(13, "/", 4, "3");
        call(13, "/", 0, "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException");
    }

    public static void call(int a, String op, int b, String expected) {
        try {
            System.out.println(Arithmetic.compute(a, op, b));
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getClass().getName());
        }
        System.out.println("Expected: " + expected);
    }
}
```

This is provided by the book as the testing class

```
public class Arithmetic
{
   /**
  Computes the value of an arithmetic expression
  @param value1 the first operand
  @param operator a string that should contain an operator + - * or /
  @param value2 the second operand
  @return the result of the operation      
   */
   public static int compute(int value1, String operator, int value2)
   {

   int a;
   a = 1;

   String b;
   b = "-";

   int c;
   c = 3;

   return (a, b, c);

   }
}
```

I dont even really know where to begin, i am completely lost at what to even do the book does a bad job of explaining what to do and my teacher is useless at helping students.

Am i supposed to make an if statement that changes operator ever time it loops? Please help.

Edit: Prompt

   Write a method that computes the value of an arithmetic expression. 
   The operator string should be one of ("+", "-", "*", or "/"). 
   The method should throw an IllegalArgumentException otherwise. 
   Also throw an IllegalArgumentException if the operator is "/" 
   and the second argument is zero.
*/

Comment: @LoganKulinski whoops ill add that in

Comment: You should change the title to something more appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `Arithmetic.compute(int, String, int)`, something like<sup>1</sup>

```
public static int compute(int value1, String operator, int value2) {
    if ("+".equals(operator)) {
        return value1 + value2;
    } else if ("-".equals(operator)) {
        return value1 - value2;
    } else if ("*".equals(operator)) {
        return value1 * value2;
    } else if ("/".equals(operator)) {
        if (value2 != 0) {
            return value1 / value2;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Division By 0");
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Unknown operator (%s)",
            operator));
}
```

then run `ArithmeticTester` and you will see that the rest of your code invokes the `compute` function and outputs diagnostic messages indicating test pass/failure conditions. The above implementation passes the provided tests.

<sup>1<sub>Using [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).</sub></sup>

Comment: Just ran it myself. Seems perfect. I'll remove my comment. I know that all the ops yield ints, I suggested casting to an `int` to make it clearer to OP.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I was expecting it to throw an ArithmeticException.

Comment: This is what I get for 1/0. `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero`

Comment: passes all but when op is not a +,-,*,/ but i got that to work by myself thanks a ton.

Comment: @RyanVanDusen That is implemented by the `throw` on the last line in `compute`.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a function that does something like this...

```
public static int compute(int val1, int val2, String op) {
    // +
    if (op.equals("+"))
        return val1 + val2;
    // -
    else if (op.equals("-"))
        return val1 - val2;
    // *
    else if (op.equals("*"))
        return val1 * val2;
    // /
    else if (op.equals("/")) {
        if(val2 == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't divide by 0");
        return (int)(val1 / val2);
    }
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Op not supported");
}
```

Let me know if something is not clear.